# Two vehicles at an intersection, using derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, word-problem

> An automobile traveling at a rate of $30$ ft/sec is approaching an intersection. When the automobile is $120$ ft from the intersection, a truck traveling at the rate of $40$ ft/sec crosses the intersection. The automobile and the truck are on roads that are at right angles to each other. How fast are the automobile and the truck seperating $2$ sec after the truck leaves the intersection?

I don't know how to do this question, could anyone help?

I have to use derivative to do this.

Comment: Is the answer 100ft/s

Comment: The answer says it's supposed to be $14$ ft/sec @ArchisWelankar

Comment: Oh then its units will be that of accleration as ds/dt is velocity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the two seconds after the truck crosses the intersection, the distance travelled by the automobile is $30\times2=60$ ft. It's distance from the intersection is now $120-60=60$ ft.

The distance travelled by the truck in this interval is $40\times2=80$ ft, which is its distance from the intersection.

Now, the automobile, the truck, and the intersection form a right angled triangle right angled at the intersection. Let the distance of the automobile from the intersection be $x$ and that of the truck be $y$. Then, by the Pythagoras theorem, the distance between each other is
$$\tag1d^2=x^2+y^2$$.

At this instant,
$d=\sqrt{60^2+80^2}=100$ ft.

Differentiating $(1)$ with respect to time,
$$2d\frac{d}{dt}(d)=2x\frac{dx}{dt}+2y\frac{dy}{dt}$$
We wish to find $\frac{d}{dt}(d)$. The values of $x,y$, and $d$ are known.
$\frac{dx}{dt}=-30$ft/sec and $\frac{dy}{dt}=40$ft/sec. Using these, the problem can be solved.

Taking appropriate units, $x=60,y=80,d=100,\frac{dx}{dt}=-30,\frac{dy}{dt}=40$

Then,

$$d\frac{d}{dt}(d)=x\frac{dx}{dt}+y\frac{dy}{dt}$$
$$100\times\frac{d}{dt}(d)=60\times(-30)+80\times40$$
$$100\times\frac{d}{dt}(d)=3200-1800=1400$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}(d)=14\text{ ft/sec}$$

Comment: Do you mind showing me more steps please? @GoodDeeds

Comment: @didgocks Also please note a typo in the sign of $\frac{dx}{dt}$ that has been corrected. It is negative as the distance is decreasing.